# ubuntu wired connection disconnected

Tags: networking

My wired connection is disconnected, it was working perfectly until two hours ago, now i can't get it established. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 this is my ifconfig :

```
ifconfig

eth0 

Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:03:73:5b:4d:c9
inet6 addr: fe80::1a03:73ff:fe5b:4dc9/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:8027 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:2586648 (2.5 MB) TX bytes:271453 (271.4 KB)

lo 

Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:1489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:120803 (120.8 KB) TX bytes:120803 (120.8 KB)

wlan0 

Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr cc:af:78:43:84:43
inet addr:192.168.43.80 Bcast:192.168.43.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::ceaf:78ff:fe43:8443/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:33351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:21387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:38779028 (38.7 MB) TX bytes:2683486 (2.6 MB)</$>
```

nmcli dev :

`DEVICE     TYPE              STATE

wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected

eth0       802-3-ethernet    disconnected`

`cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: What's the output of `nmcli dev` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Edit your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Ethernet interface manually, by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
if you get IP address thought DHCP server use below configuration

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and if you have your own static IP address user this configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5     # your static ip address
netmask 255.255.255.0   # your network netmask
gateway 192.168.1.254   # your network gateway
```

for more configuration look at 
[setting-up-an-network-interfaces](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/)

Comment: doesn't work either